# Define HOC asyncly

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Let me define my use case, it'll be easier to explain.

I'm using the package [localforage-observable](https://github.com/localForage/localForage-observable), which basically creates an Observable via `localForage.newObservable()` that fires every time an item has changed in localforage.

I then have a [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md) HOC, `mapPropsStream`, which takes this Observable and passes the value into the wrapped component.

```
  const withLocalForage = mapPropsStream((props$) => {
    return props$.pipe(
      combineLatest(localForage.newObservable(), (props, lf) => {
        return { ...props, lf };
      })
    );
  });

  export default withLocalForage
```

So that in my React component, I do

```
import './withLocalForage';

@withLocalForage
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.lf)}</div>
  }
}
```

This would work, except for one issue: `Currently localForage Observables should only be created after localforage.ready()` (localforage-observable's doc).

The only thing is that, on app load, `localForage.newObservable()` is not defined; it is only defined if I do `localForage.ready().then(() => { /* do something with localForage.newObservable() */})`

I hope the post's title is clearer now: How can I define in my case the `withLocalForage` HOC asyncly, so that it's only defined after `localForage.ready()`?

Comment: If you're using this library, consider opening an issue. It doesn't make sense to force a developer to chain `ready` and `newObservable`, this is expected to be done by the library. This approach is common, e.g. in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be reasonable for `newObservable` to chain `localforage.ready()` internally. Since this is not so, this likely should be done manually:

```
  const localforage$ = from(localForage.ready()).pipe(
    switchMap(() => localForage.newObservable())
  );

  const withLocalForage = mapPropsStream((props$) => {
    return props$.pipe(
      combineLatest(localforage$, (props, lf) => {
        return { ...props, lf };
      })
    );
  });
```